# How to call a function on when a grid is resized in Ext js 4.0?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

How to call a function on when a grid is resized in Ext js 4.0?

I am trying something like this but it ain't working.

```
Ext.define('App.view.EDM.DataModelling.Entity.entitySymbol' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel', 
alias   : 'widget.entitySymbol',
title:'Entity',
ddGroup : 'GridDDGroup',
hideHeaders : true,
stripeRows : false,
resizable : {
    resize : function(e ) {
        alert("hi1");
    },
    resizedrag : function(e ) {
        alert("hi2");
    },
    beforeresize : function(e ) {
        alert("hi3");
    }

    },  
floating:true,
draggable : true,   
loadMask : true,
height: 180,
width: 160
```

});

None of this is working.

Comment: Always look for required function or Event in the API reference.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-resize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a listener to [resize event](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-resize)

```
...
stripeRows : false,
listeners:{
  resize: function(this, width, height, oldWidth, oldHeight, eOpts){
     alert("hi4");
  }
},
...
```

Comment: This worked. I had one more question. My grid is added to a panel. When I resize the gird from right or bottom its position on panel is same. But when I resize from left or right its position changes. I want to find out this new position inside resize event listener.

Comment: take a look at http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-getPosition, you can get it like this.getPosition()